# tubular neighborhoods - problem

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Consider $\alpha:[0,L]\to \mathbb R^3$ a smooth regular simple closed curve, arc-length parametrized. Denote its trace by $\gamma$. Let $\epsilon >0$ be a real number and $N_\epsilon (\alpha)$ the set of points in $\mathbb R^3$ whose distance from $\gamma$ is at most $\epsilon$.Taking $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, then these disks don't intersect one another, and therefore, $N_\epsilon (\alpha)$ is a tubular neighborhood of $\alpha$ which  will be homeomorphic to the product of $\gamma$ and any of this disks (it would look like a curvy, solid donut).

i) Suppose at first that $k$ the curvature of $\alpha$ is positive. I have to prove that for small enough x, the function $F: D^2(\epsilon)\times [0,L] \to N_\epsilon (\alpha)$ where

$F(x,y,t):= \alpha(t)+x \mathbb N(t)+ y \mathbb B(t)$ is a diffeomorphism ($\{\mathbb T(t),\mathbb N(t),\mathbb B(t)\}$ represent the Frenet frame). (Take F is biyective for granted)

Use this to calculate the bolume of $ N_\epsilon (\alpha)$

ii) Assuming now no restriction on $k$, conclude that the volume of $ N_\epsilon (\alpha)$ equals the length of $\gamma$ times the area, $\pi{\epsilon}^2$ of any one of the disks.

Solution:

i) As we can take that $F$ is biyective for granted, we only have to prove that $F$ is a local diffeomorphism, that is, that $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are both differentiable.

By the inverse function theorem, $F$ is a local diffeomorphism if $Jac F\neq 0$

Using Frenet formulas,

det($\partial F\over \partial t$,$\partial F\over \partial x$,$\partial F\over \partial y $)= $(1-xk(t))$det($\mathbb T(t),\mathbb N(t),\mathbb B(t)$)=$(1-xk(t))$

$(1-xk(t))\neq 0$ because we can always choose an $\epsilon$ and $x$ small enough??

I don't know if I am right untill now, and how to continue.

ii) In this case, the curvature of $\alpha$ could be zero, and therefore, it is a line. So taking $\epsilon >0$ we have a cylinder (or disks) so we can easily calculate the volume at these parts. And the total volume would be the volumes of the cylinder plus the volume of the tubular neighborhoods.

I would appreciate any idea/ help. Thank you very much.

Comment: $N_\epsilon(\alpha)$ isn't a disk, so what disks are you talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about a cylinder

Comment: Have a look at your third sentence.

Comment: I mean that $N_{\epsilon}$ is the union of flat "disks" (like pipes- I don't know how to express it). Sorry for my poor English @Mercy I am not English.

Comment: Notice that your curve is a plane curve, therefore $N_\epsilon(\alpha)$ is just the union of little (straight) segments of length $2\epsilon$ which are perpendicular to $\gamma$.

Comment: It is a curve in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: You've just modified it!

Comment: yes sorry, I wrote it wrong